# Is it possible to drive a 6 or 5 lead stepper motor with 3 phase inverter/bldc driver

Tags: power, inverter, mosfet-driver

I wanted a good way to test my inverter circuit and all I have is a 6 lead stepper motor and a 5 lead stepper motor. Would this work for testing? I have no idea how I would wire the motor. I own a  Adafruit 858 Unipolar stepper motor (5 lead ) and a Decitek 33275-P26 stepper motor (6 lead). I was not able to find documentation on the Decitek stepper motor. I am extremely unfamiliar working with stepper motors. I understand that inverters produce 3 phases of ac 120 degrees out of phase with one another. To my knowledge most bldc motors operate with 3 coils than can accept the 3 phase inverter output. However I am not sure if there is a way to modify the stepper motor inputs/ connect in a certain way such that I could produce rotation with either of these stepper motors. When I pull up documentation for the unipolar stepper motor I find that it is essentially 2 coils connected by a center tap. Is this possible without external circuitry.

Comment: Could you tell us more information? What stepper motor do you have? What have you tried/googled untill now? Edit your question to add those info.

Comment: A quick answer is NO. Totally different and incompatible devices.

Comment: How did you get from stepper motors to BLDC?  They are fundamentally different.

Comment: I understand that they are different but there are some really smart people in this world. I was wondering if anyone found some sort of unique way of jerry rigging a stepper motor to behave like a bldc